# PHP Array to Bash not Working

Tags: php, arrays, bash

Sorry for the silly question here today.

I am passing a PHP array to a bash script using `implode();`.

To test, I am echoing the implode and I can see all array items there, but when I `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"` only the first element of the array is printed.

Am I missing something?

Here is more info:

PHP:

```
$files = $_POST['files'];    
$files2 = implode(" ", $files);
echo $files2   ## I can see full output here. 
shell_exec ("./sequential.sh $files2");
```

Bash:

```
files = $1
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" >> mytempfile.txt
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: $files2 should be string and not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> files = $1

`$1` is only the first argument. If you want all arguments then you can find them in `$@`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" >> mytempfile.txt
```

Comment: Ok, I tested that and got pretty close. It did print the full contents. I suppose I should have included this in my post but I edited out a lot of the script. I am passing 4 other variables from PHP to bash, so if I use `$@` it prints ALL the variables, but I only need whats in the array. So now to figure that out.

Comment: `$@` contains all the parameters passed to the shell script in the command line.

Comment: I marked yours correct as it was correct for how I posed the question, but I think I need to figure it out further to get it handling all the parameters correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fcamp Pass the other 4 arguments first, then use `files=({@:5}")` to make `files` an array containing the arguments starting with `$5`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the syntax is off a bit in your example, but it got me exactly where I needed to go! It should be `files=${@:5}`. This works.

Comment: @fcamp Oops, I did get the syntax a bit wrong, but not that way. `files=${@:5}` sets `files` as a string (*not* array) containing the arguments from `$5` on separated by spaces; if you refer to it as `$files` (without double-quotes around it), it'll be re-split into the individual elements *unless* any of them contain spaces or wildcards (in which case weird things happen). `files=("{@:5}")` (note the fixed double-quote), on the other hand, sets `files` as an array; if you refer to it as `"${files[@]}"`, it'll be expanded into its elements *without* any confusion about spaces or wildcards.

Comment: @GordonDavisson ah yes, I see that now. What I ended up doing was just reading it from $files to rebuild the array like so : `IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$files"
` . If I use your steps above then I can skip that which makes it easier to read. Thanks for all your help.